# What would be 1850's equivalent of slang praise for being audacious?

Tags: expressions, american-english, slang, history

What might an 1850's working class American man say as praise to another man for being really audacious such as equivalent of "You crazy mf" or "crazy ass"?

Comment: American language hadn't become uniform by the 1850's and slang was regionalized at that time. Do you want to narrow it down to a particular region?

Comment: Are you those two well-understood idioms for the sense that you describe? Has that usage been documented? Please cite a source for the sense you are looking for a phrase for.

Comment: @CanisLupus Slang is normalized and standardized now?

Comment: @kris I think we have a more uniform understanding of it. It still may retain its local usage. But you're right, it's not universal.

Comment: ODO *slang:* "A type of language consisting of words and phrases that are regarded as very informal, are more common in speech than writing, and are **typically restricted to a particular context or group of people** " [emphasis mine] http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slang

Comment: For Lord in Heaven's sake, **do not use an apostrophe if you are just giving the plural**.  "by the 1850s slang was..."  "I have 70s style hair..." {I actually do!}  "We need to find a house in the 150s price range..." etc.

Comment: the title here is a rare correct use of an apostrophe (possession) in that situation.

Comment: "Slang is normalized and standardized now" ... Canis clearly explained it was not **regionally** uniform.

Comment: @JoeBlow Can something that is regional, be "not regionally uniform?"

Answer (score 1):

John Bartlett, [*Dictionary of Americanisms*](http://books.google.com/books?id=nHgCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA388&dq=%22scrouger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3YhYVIWsEOf7igKl24CQAQ&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22scrouger%22&f=false), second edition (1859) identifies several terms from various parts of the United States that might suit. From New York:

> HIGHBINDER. A riotous fellow. New York slang.

From what was then considered the Western part of the United States:

> SCROUGER. A bouncing fellow or girl. A Western vulgarism.

and

> SNORTER. 1. A dashing, riotous fellow. A vulgar Western term.

Or you could scan through the pages of the online version of the dictionary for other possibilities.

---

The same dictionary lists three adjectives that (at the time) had the sense of "bold" or "resolute": *chunked* (a "South-west" term), *flat-footed* (a "Western" term), and *fresh* (no region specified).

So if your 1850s character is in New York, his friend might call him a "fresh highbinder"; and if in California, a "flat-footed scrouger."